# Changing content within fancybox using jquery.html()

Tags: jquery, fancybox, reload

So I have a fancy box with a link in it.

fancybox content:

```
<a href="#" class="precilink">preci description</a>
<div id="precitext">
   text changed by clicking preci
</div>
```

Now I have this jquery up top:

```
    $(".precilink").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#precitext').html("hello");
    });
```

But nothing happens, although in the dom the precitext id html gets change. How do I tell fancybox to reload?

Comment: Woops... so I was using an id but I had that precitext div in multiple areas on the page (multiple fancyboxes) changing this to (".precitext") worked just fine. I'll leave the question up just so people can see how to manipulate inside fancy boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for normal useage of fancybox, the link must point to the div. it may not be necessary in this case, but its worth a shot

```
<a href="#precitext" class="precilink">preci description</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use live event because javascript is dynamical inserted in DOM.

```
$(".precilink").live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#precitext').html("hello");
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using .text instead of .html.

```
$(".precilink").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#precitext').text("hello");
});
```